# How to determine weblogic server startup?

Tags: weblogic8.x, startupscript

I am trying to write a script that will run and send a notification email regarding a successful server restart, however, how should i do so in the best way?

Weblogic 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way, but assuming you are working in a Linux/Unix environment you could try this script.  This will watch your Weblogic start up script for a keyword (I chose "in RUNNING mode").

```
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -le 5 ]
do
 grep "started in RUNNING mode" <full path and name of log file>
 if [ $? -eq 0 ];
 then
      mail -s 'Server started' your_email@mail.com </dev/null
      break
 fi
 COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
 sleep 6
done
```